# Type matching fail in definition of function

Tags: haskell

I have produced the following data type for talking about plans of towns.

```
data Plan a = Empty | Road (Town a)(Town a) (Plan a) deriving(Eq, Show)
type Town a = a
type Neighbourhood a = [Town a]
```

I want to create a function `neighbour` which makes a list of those towns which are related by roads to a given town. I tried as follows:

```
neighbour :: Eq a => Plan a -> Town a -> Neighbourhood a
neighbour Empty _ = []
neighbour (Road (Town(m,n)) (Town(s,t)) z) (Town (c,d)) | Town(c,d) == Town(m,n) && z == Empty  = [(s,t)]
                                                        | Town(c,d) == Town(m,n) && z/= Empty = (s,t) : neighbour z Town(c,d)
                                                        | Town(c,d) /= Town(m,n) && z == Empty = []
                                                        | Town(c,d) /= Town(m,n) && z /= Empty = neighbour z Town(c,d)
```

This produces the errors:

```
 <interactive>:1133:105: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘((), ()) -> [((), ())]’
              with actual type ‘[Town a]’
• The function ‘neighbour’ is applied to three arguments,
  but its type ‘Plan a -> Town a -> [Town a]’ has only two
  In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘neighbour z Town (c, d)’
  In the expression: (s, t) : neighbour z Town (c, d)
• Relevant bindings include
    z :: Plan a (bound at <interactive>:1132:41)
    neighbour :: Plan a -> Town a -> Neighbourhood a
      (bound at <interactive>:1131:1)

 <interactive>:1135:98: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘((), ()) -> Neighbourhood a’
              with actual type ‘[Town a]’
• The function ‘neighbour’ is applied to three arguments,
  but its type ‘Plan a -> Town a -> [Town a]’ has only two
  In the expression: neighbour z Town (c, d)
  In an equation for ‘neighbour’:
      neighbour (Road (Town (m, n)) (Town (s, t)) z) (Town (c, d))
        | Town (c, d) == Town (m, n) && z == Empty = [(s, t)]
        | Town (c, d) == Town (m, n) && z /= Empty
        = (s, t) : neighbour z Town (c, d)
        | Town (c, d) /= Town (m, n) && z == Empty = []
        | Town (c, d) /= Town (m, n) && z /= Empty
        = neighbour z Town (c, d)
• Relevant bindings include
    z :: Plan a (bound at <interactive>:1132:41)
    neighbour :: Plan a -> Town a -> Neighbourhood a
      (bound at <interactive>:1131:1)
```

I presume this is a typing error, but what is the typing error and how I can rectify my definition of the function `neighbour`?

Answer (score 0):

```
data Plan a = Empty | Road (Town a) (Town a) (Plan a) deriving(Eq, Show)
newtype Town a = Town a deriving (Show,Eq)
type Neighbourhood a = [Town a]

neighbour :: (Eq a, Eq b) => Plan (a,b) -> Town (a,b) -> Neighbourhood (a,b)
neighbour Empty _ = []
neighbour (Road (Town (m,n)) (Town (s,t)) z) (Town (c,d)) | (Town (c,d)) == (Town (m,n)) && z == Empty  = [Town (s,t)]
                                                        | (Town (c,d)) == (Town (m,n)) && z/= Empty = (Town (s,t)) : neighbour z (Town (c,d))
                                                        | (Town (c,d)) /= (Town (m,n)) && z == Empty = []
                                                        | (Town (c,d)) /= (Town (m,n)) && z /= Empty = neighbour z (Town (c,d))
```

I've made some changes to your code so it compiles and loads into GHCI. Don't have time to do much else at the moment, but some points were:

- derived Show,Eq for Town
- updated the Town type signature
- added spaces in type constructors
- updated the type signature for the neighbour function to specifically talk about (a,b) tuples

I hope someone more knowledgeable can improve this answer or provide more pointers